# Is there a way to fix XML to more readable form without manual work?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML-file from a third party and values are really hard to specify in XSLT. Example of a one "object" below. I find really hard to specify values between the strings. docrev, which has value of '-' , as example.

```
<object level="1" id="2018488">
<integer>
<name>level</name>
<value>1</value>
</integer>
<string>
<name>docrev</name>
<value>-</value>
</string>
<string>
<name>DocID</name>
<value>2018488</value>
</string>
<string>
<name>Custom_Pos</name>
</string>
<string>
<name>Custom_Qty</name>
</string>
<string>
<name>DocDescr</name>
<value>Levy</value>
</string>
<date>
<name>StatusDate</name>
<value>2012-04-30</value>
</date>
</object>
```

Comment: What kind of different formatting exactly do you want? Or which XSLT code do you have currently that seems to "hard to specify"?

Comment: <xsl::value-of select="docrev"/>
Will not print the '-'.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it sounds as if you are having trouble retrieving and printing the value of the `<value>` element.

The code that you posted would be looking for a `<docrev>` element, which does not exist in your document.

It sounds as if you want to select the value of the `<value>` element that has a sibling `<name>` element with a value of `docrev`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/object/*[name='docrev']/value"/>
```

If you only want the values from `<string>` elements, you can make that XPath more specific:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/object/string[name='docrev']/value"/>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot of this answer! I am a noob, so great that you understood what I really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `<xsl:value-of select="docrev"/>` is supposed to select an element named `docrev` in XPath so it can't select an element based on the string value `docrev`.

In XSLT you can however easily define keys to select elements (or in general nodes) by a certain value, so for your example you can use a key

```
<xsl:key name="value" match="object/*/value" use="../name"/>
```

and then in the context of your sample you could use `key('value', 'docrev')` to select the corresponding `value` element respectively `<xsl:value-of select="key('value', 'docrev')"/>` to output its value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="value" match="object/*/value" use="../name"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('value', 'docrev')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwW/1

Or in a broader context you could first index the `object` elements by the `id` attribute with another key `<xsl:key name="id" match="object" use="@id"/>` and then use that together with the previous key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="id" match="object" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:key name="value" match="object/*/value" use="../name"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('value', 'docrev', key('id', '2018488'))"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwW

Using schemas or DTDs you can also predefine certain attributes or nodes as `ID`s and then use the `id` function similar to the above `key` use.

Answer (score 0):

### How to make XML be more readable

XSLT output will be more readable when you specify that indentation be used when the output XML is serialized:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

You can run any XML through XSLT via an identity tranformation if your sole purpose is to pretty-print the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```